# Save information both in sessions and in cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, navigation, session-cookies

Would it be okay to save the same navigation data in a session (server-side) and in a cookie (client-side) so that a user whose browser allows cookies can have the same advantages that one whose browser is?

The only difference would be that, while the user whose browser allows cookies can log weeks later and have he's navigation information remembered (language, etc.), the other only would be as long as his browser is not closed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a generality (meaning you could fudge it if you wanted), if you use sessions it has to put a cookie on the user's computer so the correct session can be pulled up, so there really wouldn't be an advantage. If they allow cookies, they can have a session.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Makes a lot of sense though. So, the only thing I should have to check previously is that if the user allows cookies or not, and if he does, I save it directly into the cookie. Otherwise, into the $_SESSION

Comment: You will probably need to pass around some sort of session ID if they don't allow cookies so you can continue to use the $_SESSION variable, but in either case you can use it (whether with or without cookies).

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference would be that, while the user whose browser allows
>   cookies can log weeks later and have he's navigation information
>   remembered (language, etc.), the other only would be as long as his
>   browser is not closed, right?

It depends on how long you keep session data in database. Session data in database and in cookie works almost equally. Only difference is from where you get your session data - cookie or database. Cookies have expiration time, database records - how often you clear session table.